# Can you use IConfiguration.GetSection() to read environment variables?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am using `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` in .NET 6. I am trying to use `IConfiguration.GetSection("MySection")` to read all of the environment variables with the prefix `MySection` but it is not working.

For additional context: I want to do this so I can populate various application settings classes from the "Application settings" tab in an Azure Functions app.

**Am I doing something wrong or is this use case not supported?**

Here is my program:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Text.Json;

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MySection__MyProperty", "fromEnvironmentVariable");
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

Console.WriteLine(
    "Environment variable = " + 
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MySection__MyProperty")
);

Console.WriteLine(
    "configuration[\"MySection:MyProperty\"] = " + 
    configuration["MySection:MyProperty"]
);

Console.WriteLine(
    "configuration.GetSection(\"MySection\") = " +
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(configuration.GetSection("MySection"))
);
```

The program outputs:

```
Environment variable = fromEnvironmentVariable
configuration["MySection:MyProperty"] = fromEnvironmentVariable
configuration.GetSection("MySection") = {"Key":"MySection","Path":"MySection","Value":null}
```

I want the `Value` in the last line to contain `fromEnvironmentVariable` but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line;

```cs
JsonSerializer.Serialize(configuration.GetSection("MySection"))
```

To this;

```cs
JsonSerializer.Serialize(configuration.GetSection("MySection").GetChildren())
```

Comment: Perfect! `configuration.Get<MySection>()` still doesn't work so I guess I will have to write a bit of code to map the key-value pairs to the properties of my settings class.

Comment: Realized I just needed to do `configuration.GetSection("MySection").Get<MySection>()` to bind the environment variables to the corresponding settings class.